# Does Linux have their own keys?

Tags: linux, keyboard

I don't own a Linux computer, or even a Unix one, so I decided to ask.

In Windows, they have their own key named the Windows key (<kbd>⊞</kbd>). On its own, it opens the start menu and pressing it with another key will perform a certain function.

In Apple's macOS, they have their own key named the command key (<kbd>⌘</kbd>). It acts like Windows' <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. For Windows users, if they would use macOS, they can simply replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>⌘</kbd> for most functions, if not all.

As for Linux, I have no idea what keys they have that others don't.

So does Linux have their own keys?

Comment: Linux is just the operating system kernel. There are many ways of interacting with Linux, for example the command line, but also many different Desktop environments or GUIs. This is unlike Windows or Mac, each having one and only one GUI. GUIs can be configured to use any key or key combination as "hot key". In many cases, you will find that they use the Windows key or the Mac Command key by default. Since there are not specific Linux keyboards, in contrast to Apple or Microsoft keyboards, there is no specific Linux key.

Comment: It's often called the 'super' key by those who don't want to call it the Windows key. Yes, it is still used (depending on many things, but most often yes) and it does many of the things you'd expect it to do (again, depending on many things, but most often yes).

Comment: So I read there is a <kbd>Meta</kbd> key in Unix computers. Can't seem to find the definition of it being used in Unix, only in SAIL computers.

Comment: On PC keyboards, the Meta key is usually labelled `Alt`. It may specifically be the right `alt` key.

Comment: No, Windows, Macintosh, and Unix do no actually have their own keys. Keyboard hardware manufacturers make keyboards that send specific signals and scan codes to the operating system, and the operating system interprets them however it wishes. This is how and why Mac often interprets the "Apple" key as a "Control" key. Un\*x systems usually have drivers that let _you_ define which keys are "special" as well as what to do when it receives the scan code for those keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "special" keys of which you speak are not defined by Linux or Unix, but by the desktop environment in use on the specific machine. That said, [this answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys) gives a short course on Unixy keyboard layouts.